# Type aliasing Java classes with statics

Tags: scala

Suppose `MyClass` is a class defined in Java, and has many static as well as non-static members. I tried to alias this class (and associated companion object) in a Scala object `MyObject` as shown below:

```
object MyObject {
  import javastuff._
  type MyAlias = MyClass
  val MyAlias = MyClass
}
```

Scalac complains:

```
error: object MyClass is not a value
val MyAlias = MyClass
```

How do I work around this? Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to use `val MyAlias` for? Type aliasing is done with the `type` keyword, which you have already done. `val MyAlias` is a value declaration, MyClass is a type name and not a value, so u can't assign MyClass to `val MyAlias`. Please give us a few use cases.

Comment: @Wong, since invocation of Java's static methods are done with JavaClass.staticMethod, as if JavaClass were a Scala `object`, @Siddharth want's a way to "alias" this representation of class methods the same way that it can be achieved in Scala in regard with Scala's `object`s, e.g. `val obj=scalaObject` .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although this works in pure Scala for a class + companion object, it's not possible with Java's static methods, as these don't belong to any interface.

Scala *could*, in theory, create an object containing delegates to all the static methods of some class, but it doesn't do this currently.  It's also possible to write a compiler plugin for this if you feel comfortable writing plugins.

Failing that, you'll either have to create an object full of delegates yourself, or just cherry-pick a few methods and pass them around as functions.

Comment: And thus we register yet another corner case in Scala. <*sigh*>

Comment: It's a corner case alright, but this one ain't Scala's. I can just see the JVM right now at some bar, having been accused of not using protection and engaging in activities that aren't object-oriented: "But she (Scala) was just asking for it! She may have said no, but I know she meant yes. She's just a tease and it's her fault for sitting on my lap in the first place..."

Answer (score 1):

> it's not possible with Java's static methods, as these don't belong to any interface.

Update 5 years later: [PR 5131](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/5131) mentions:

> We used to disable generation of static forwarders when a object had a
>   trait as a companion, as one could not add methods with bodies to an
>   interface in JVM 6.
>
> The JVM lifted this restriction to support default methods in interfaces,
>   so we can lift the restriction on static forwarders, too.
>
> Fixes [scala-dev issue 59](https://github.com/scala/scala-dev/issues/59)

See [commit 41c9a17](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/41c9a17e4f211fc24a931949a0819a0474cc004a) by [Jason Zaugg (`retronym`)](https://github.com/retronym).

Comment: Question 5 more years later: what are the implications of those commits / fixes on how can the problem in the question be handled?

Comment: @Suma Not sure: I was just mentioning one new feature which made the original problem no longer impossible, but I don't know if that has been implemented since then. Opaque type in Scala 3 might be involved, for instance: https://blog.rockthejvm.com/scala-3-opaque/.

Comment: Could you explain how allowing static forwarders in traits/interfaces allows (or doesn't allow) what the OP wants? Does the compiler also pretend to make companions for Java classes now? (because I just tried something similar to the OP's code and it didn't work)

Comment: @user It could allow the first sentence of the accepted answer to be somehow implemented.

Comment: @VonC Oh, ok, I got excited for a second thinking there was some way to actually alias Java classes :(